# Работа с несколькими функциями

Tags: python, функции, список

У меня три функций, каждая возвращает 3-4 значения, которые я хочу использовать как аргументы для следующих функций.
Пример:

```
a = 1
def func1(arg0):
    return (arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)


def func2(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4):
    return (arg5,arg6,arg7)

func2(arg1=func1(arg0=a)[0],arg2=func1(arg0=a)[1],arg3=func1(arg0=a)[2],arg4=func1(arg0=a)[3])
```

Этот код работает, но теперь мне необходима третья(последняя) функция, в которой на входе будут аргументы arg5,arg6,arg7

Код уже не работает - выдает ошибку:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Наверно, я действительно слишком усложнил, но не знаю, как выйти из ситуации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Но до конца понятно, что именно вам нужно, но рассмотрите такой вариант.

```py
func3(*func2(*func1(a)))
```

В `func2` в качестве аргументов передадутся элементы кортежа, который вернет `func1`. Таким же образом результат `func2` пойдет на вход `func3`

Comment: А почему вы записали func1(a) , а не func1(arg0=a) ?

Comment: В данном случае разницы нет. Если аргументы идут в том же порядке, что и пареметры, указывать имена не обязательно.

Comment: @КириллВишняков   Потому что функция `def func1(arg0)` принимает позиционный аргумент.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает